# Calculus-Tangent Line

Tags: calculus, functions

> Find the cordinates of the point on the curve $f(x)=xe^{2x}+1$ where the tangent of the tangent line is horizontal.

I am not sure of what to do.

Comment: Well, let's start with what the question means: What does it mean for the tangent line to be horizontal, in terms of the derivative?

Comment: A horizontal tangent line is a line that has a slope 0

Comment: Right. Now can you relate the slope of the tangent line with the derivative of the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a horizontal tangent line, set $f'(x)=0$, where $f'$ is the derivative of $f$.
\begin{align}0=f'(x)&=\frac{d}{dx}(xe^{2x}+1) \\
&=\frac{d}{dx}(xe^{2x})+\frac{d}{dx}(1) \\
&=e^{2x}(1+2x)  \end{align}
If $e^{2x}(1+2x)=0$, then $1+2x=0$, since $e^{2x} \not=0$ for all real numbers $x$. From $1+2x=0$, we get the root $x=-\frac{1}{2}$. Thus, the horizontal tangent line of $f$ occurs at $x=-\frac{1}{2}$. Plugging $x=-\frac{1}{2}$ into $f$ yields $$f\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{2e-1}{2e}.$$
The coordinate of the location at which the tangent line is horizontal is $\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{2e-1}{2e}\right)$.

Comment: f(-1/2) = xe^2x + 1 = (-1/2)e^(2*-1/2) + 1 = (-1/2)e^(-2/2) + 1 = (-1/2)e^(-1) + 1 = (-1/2)(1/e) + 1 = -1/2e + 1 How did you get 2e-1/2e?